# Deleting dict in list of dictionaries - not all elements are deleted, need loop several times

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with length 793. When i try to delete elements from list based on if statement, not all elements are deleted. Several elements still stays in list, all elements are deleted only after several iterations of same code.

```
>>> len(data_list)
    793
    >>> for i, device in enumerate(data_list):
    ...  if 'PSS' in device['type']:
    ...   print (i)
    ...   del (data_list[i])
    ...
    47
    83
    127
    207
    279
    ...
    ...
    734
    745
    746
    747
    >>> for i, device in enumerate(data_list):
    ...  if 'PSS' in device['type']:
    ...   print (i)
    ...   del (data_list[i])
    ...
    279
    313
    355
    399
    440
    443
    471
    499
    505
    515
    528
    734
    >>> for i, device in enumerate(data_list):
    ...  if 'PSS' in device['type']:
    ...   print (i)
    ...   del (data_list[i])
    ...
    734
    >>> for i, device in enumerate(data_list):
    ...  if 'PSS' in device['type']:
    ...   print (i)
    ...   del (data_list[i])
    ...
    >>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating on a list and deleting/adding element at the same time on it is not a good idea, because when you delete element at index `i`, the next one (`i+1`) moves to position `i` **but** the loop continues and gives you `i+1` so you miss it. In fact you'll miss element that are just after an element that match

The better way is the opposite : keeping the ones that matches

- using list comphrehension

  ```
  data_list = [device for device in data_list if 'PSS' in device['type']]
  ```
- using filter

  ```
  data_list = list(filter(lambda device:'PSS' in device['type'], data_list))
  ```